# Как настроить dns для локальной сети или создать свою доменную зону?

Tags: dns, localhost, domain

Помогите настроить dns для локальной сети.
На одном пк установлено Ubuntu server 18.04
Установлена FASTPANEL
Создан сайт home.lan
сейчас открывается по адресу 192.168.0.107:7777/home.lan
Как сделать чтобы открывался по адресу home.lan и чтобы все остальные сайты типа home1.lan, dom.lan, site.lan
открывались по домену *.lan?
Доступ к сайтам должен быть у всех кто подключен к этой локальной сети
В наличии есть роутер mikrotik.

Comment: самое простое - ввести статические записи

https://asp24.com.ua/blog/mikrotik-manipulyacii-s-dns-dobavliaem-staticheskie-dns-zapisi/

Comment: Нужно вводить все сайты или можно сделать для всего домена? Например *.loc

Comment: Нужно вводить все сайты. Что бы автоматически, при условии, что адреса раздает тот же Микротик через dhcp, тогда надо настраивать связку dhcp + dns. Что бы dhcp делал запись в dns когда выдает адрес для компа в локалке.

Answer (score 0):

В панели управления FASTPANEL есть возможность включения DNS службы. Затем в настройках Microtik Вы можете добавить 192.168.0.107 как один из DNS серверов.

При создании сайта панель управления сама добавит A запись в DNS.